# Configuration Tool/Console from Enterprise Library 6 with Visual Studio 2013 Throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash, filenotfoundexception, enterprise-library-6

I'm experimenting with EntLib6 and Visual Studio 2013.

When I attempt to open the web.config with the EntLibConfig.exe or EntLibConfig-32.exe, I get the following exception:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   entlibconfig.exe
Problem Signature 02:   6.0.1304.0
Problem Signature 03:   51795f05
Problem Signature 04:   EntLibConfig
Problem Signature 05:   6.0.1304.0
Problem Signature 06:   51795f05
Problem Signature 07:   3
Problem Signature 08:   29
Problem Signature 09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   25bb
Additional Information 2:   25bbdf70ded93ca74287ca4dc5fdb6ca
Additional Information 3:   86d3
Additional Information 4:   86d3c846a76cb9420f22a0b4ef52ed43

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I'm experimenting with the sample here - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Use-Jquery-Autocomplete-a2e3e42e#content  (Use Jquery Autocomplete With Web Service (ASMX) DataSource)

My machine is Windows 7 64 bit, VS2013 Update 2. Which file is it referring to and how do I get past this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for these dll's and see if they are in the folder with Entlibconfig.exe.  It looks like Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll is the problem most of the time.  At least it has been a problem for me in the past.

`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design.HostAdapterV5.dll 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.DesignTime.dll 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll`

Comment: @RJN I can't really remember.  I think I just reinstalled the enterprise library.  But I am not 100% sure. I may have uninstalled it then did a fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

Check to have following files. These make possible to load the console and use Logging Application Block with Database Trace Listener.

- EntLibConfig.exe EntLibConfig.exe.config
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design.HostAdapter.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design.HostAdapterV5.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.DesignTime.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.EnvironmentalOverrides.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.dll

Answer (score 2):

For those that find this years from now (like I just did): if you downloaded the EL binaries, after installation, there's a PowerShell script, `install-packages.ps1`.  Running it results in a number of additional DLLs (and who knows what else) being downloaded to the local directory, and then EntLibConfig runs fine.

Comment: When I tried to install the ps1, I get error: WARNING: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. Any idea why it fails to get other binaries?

Comment: @RJN Nope. Firewall or network config issue at your site, maybe?

Comment: Thanks!! I hope there is a better documentation!

Comment: Followup now that I've run into a problem w/install-packages.ps1 getting "remote connection forcibly closed" on my new laptop: I got around this by grabbing nuget.exe from MS and hacking install-packages.ps1 to point to the new nuget.exe rather than the one that came with EL. You'll probably have to change your PowerShell script permissions if you haven't already, because hacking will probably bollix up the signature block.